# Mongoose importing models won't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I define my schema and models in the same file that I use them, everything works just fine.

However, if I import them like I see all of the examples on the net import them: like this...

**index.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./../models/user');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/demo_database', function(){
    var user = new User({...});
});
```

**user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSch = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSch);
```

...then any functions I run on on any instances of User in index.js will just hang.

I have worked around this by passing the mongoose variable to user.js like this...

**index.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./../models/user')(mongoose);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/demo_database', function(){
    var user = new User({...});
});
```

**user.js**

```
module.exports = function(mongoose) {

    var UserSch = new mongoose.Schema({
        ...
    });

    return mongoose.model('user', UserSch);
}
```

Why am I having to do this while all of the examples I've seen, don't?

Thanks!

**Additional Info**

If I move user.js to the same folder as index.js and do `var User = require('./user')`, everything works as expected.

Comment: First you need to connect the mongoose! Look at my example: https://github.com/Talento90/ima-up/

Comment: @MarcoTalento I am, I just left that part out of this post for brevity. Like I said, it works when its all in the same file. When the models imported though, I can see the connection in the mongodb logs but the .find or .save callbacks are never called and the script hangs.

Comment: @MarcoTalento I edited the post to show where I'm calling mongoose.connect()

Answer (score 0):

Try this code!!!

**index.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose .connect(connectionString)
var mongoDb = mongoose.connection

mongoDb.on('error', () => {
  server.log('error', `Unable to connect to database: ${config.database.connectionString}`)
})

mongoDb.once('open', () => {
  server.log('info', `Connected to database: ${config.database.connectionString}`)
})


// Load all Mongoose models
require('./../models/user');

//Using Model
var userModel = mongoose.model('user');

userModel.findOne({ _id: "id..." })
```

**User.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSch = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSch);
```

Comment: So essentially what you've done here is move the connection to happen before the models are imported into index.js?